# .NET ClosedXML - force Excel sheet to recognize formatting

Tags: .net, excel, date-formatting, closedxml

(Repost of additional edit to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956083/net-excel-file-generated-via-data-table-where-to-add-formatting))

I'm building an Excel workbook by adding a data set, then adding formatting to specific columns. Code sample:

```
    var wb = new XLWorkbook();
    wb.Worksheets.Add(ds);
    foreach (IXLWorksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
    {
        if (value == 1)
        {
            ws.Column(16).Style.DateFormat.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            ws.Column(17).Style.DateFormat.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        }
        else
        { }
    }

    return wb;
```

When I look at the final document, the dates are still displaying as verbose - 12/7/2017 12:00:00 AM - but the formatting IS in the document. If I do the manual "hit enter in the cell and exit" thing, the formatting updates, as does doing Text to Columns.

Of course, I don't WANT to do that, I want the formatting to take straight away.

I assume the issue is that I'm adding the data first and formatting it after, just like a regular sheet. But is there a command in there to refresh/apply/what have you the formatting? I fear since there's no such command in Excel itself (Any why not, to digress slightly) there may be none here, but it's worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on [GitHub](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/707), I can't replicate your problem with your code.

Here is a code sample that works perfectly on my machine:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            var dataSet = GetDataSet();

            // Add all DataTables in the DataSet as a worksheets
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dataSet);

            var ws = wb.Worksheets.First();

            ws.Column(4).Style.DateFormat.Format = "d MMMM yyyy";

            wb.SaveAs("outputfile.xlsx");
        }
    }

    private static DataSet GetDataSet()
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(GetTable("Patients"));
        ds.Tables.Add(GetTable("Employees"));
        ds.Tables.Add(GetTable("Information"));
        return ds;
    }

    private static DataTable GetTable(String tableName)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.TableName = tableName;
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", new DateTime(2000, 1, 1));
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", new DateTime(2000, 1, 2));
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", new DateTime(2000, 1, 3));
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", new DateTime(2000, 1, 4));
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", new DateTime(2000, 1, 5));
        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, then I don't have an explanation. If, when you open that Excel doc, the date column comes up as you request, then I don't get why it''s not coming up formatted in mine.

Comment: @VBartilucci So do you realise why it's so important to give a code sample that we can run and reproduce the problem?

Comment: I understand that you maintain it's working for you, and since I can't see the excel file you generated, I'll take you at your word. I can't supply the dataset I'm adding to my sheet as it contains personal data.  I surmised the issue was based on Excel's limitation about not displaying formatting changes without a reset of the cells in question, but if it's working for you, there's some other issue.  You've not answered the question about if such a command exists perhaps an analogue to text to column, so I'll assume there isn't. Don't trouble yourself any further.